# Iterate through a list of objects and skip one index and read it later again

Tags: java, list, for-loop, arraylist, iterator

I have an ArrayList, which contains String name, String description, String url.
I'm iterating through the list

I have the list of websites

### Name  --  Domain

```
   - Apple  www.apple.com 
   - Bing   www.bing.com 
   - Google www.google.com 
   - Hilton www.hiltonhotels.com 
   - Ink    www.ink.com
```

while iterating through the above list, i want to skip 'Hilton' for one time and let 'Ink' go just before in this iteration.

```
List<Domain> dmn = new ArrayList<Domain>();
for(Domain names:dmn) {
    if(dmn.get(0).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Hilton")) {
        int index = 0;
        dmn.subList(index, index+1);                       
    }
}
```

Basically i want to change the index of Hilton by 1 value. How can i achieve using list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be the one you tried:

```
//i've encapsulated the sorting code in a method that receives a list as a parameter.
private List<Domain> sortDomains1(final List<Domain> domains)
{
    //this is a tempList that will be returned from subList method.
    List<Domain> tempList = null;
    //as your using iterator anonymously, you have to implement an index
    int i = 0;
    for(final Domain domain : domains) 
    {
        //looking for 'Hilton'.
        if(domain.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Hilton")) 
        {
            //here we're getting a sublist of 2 elements that need to be switched in positions
            tempList = domains.subList(i, i+2); //have to get 2 elements
            break; //if we'have found it, then we leaven the loop and switch positions;
        }
        //increasing an index of the array
        i++;
    }

    //having a subList we can change the order. It will also change it in the original list.
    Domain tempDomain; //we have to make a switch, so we need a temp Domain.
    tempDomain = tempList.get(1); //the one after hilton will be temp.
    tempList.set(1, tempList.get(0));  //put hilton in second position
    tempList.set(0, tempDomain);       //put temp in first.

    return domains;
}
```

In general you shouldn't use `for(Domain names:dmn)` for Collection modifications as modifying a Collection while iterating [can result in unexpected behaviuor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755592/concurrent-modification-exception-while-iterating-over-arraylist). [Setting values should not create any problems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (only operations that resize array are problematic), but if you'll change your mind and would like to remove some domains you'll have to rewrite the whole loop statement (or you'll forget and something bad will happen). (You can use [ListIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624220/java-adding-elements-to-list-while-iterating-over-it) if would like to use that solution).

Try using `for(int i = 0; i < domains.size(); i++)` loop instead. In that case you can manipulate on the list.
The `dmn.subList(index, index+1);` you used would get you a list with one element - Hilton domain - and would not change anything in the original list. So I've substituted it with `ArrayList.set() methods.`

```
private List<Domain> sortDomains2(final List<Domain> domains)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < domains.size(); i++) {
        if(domains.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Hilton")) 
        {
            Domain temp = domains.get(i);
            domains.set(i, domains.get(i+1));
            domains.set(i+1, temp);
            i++;
        }
    }

    return domains;
}
```

This method is more flexible, because you can make more changes + all I wrote above.
In both cases you could add additional param to those methods - name of element to move, or domain to move, i.e:

```
private List<Domain> sortDomains2(final List<Domain> domains, final String elementToMove)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < domains.size(); i++) 
    {
        if(domains.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(elementToMove)) 
        {
            Domain temp = domains.get(i);
            domains.set(i, domains.get(i+1));
            domains.set(i+1, temp);
            i++;
        }
    }

    return domains;
}
```

This way you will be able to move more elements by calling:

```
List<Domain> sortedDomains2 = sortDomains2(new ArrayList<Domain>(domains), "Bing");
sortedDomains2 = sortDomains2(new ArrayList<Domain>(sortedDomains2), "Hilton");
```

The whole code for testing:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Main().run();
    }

    private void run()
    {
        List<Domain> domains = getDomains();

        System.out.println("Domains before sorting: " + domains);

        List<Domain> sortedDomains1 = sortDomains1(new ArrayList<Domain>(domains));
        List<Domain> sortedDomains2 = sortDomains2(new ArrayList<Domain>(domains));

        System.out.println("Domains after sorting by method1: " + sortedDomains1);
        System.out.println("Domains after sorting by method2: " + sortedDomains2);

        System.out.println("Original list: " + domains);
    }

    private List<Domain> sortDomains1(final List<Domain> domains)
    {
        List<Domain> tempList = null;
        int i = 0;
        for(final Domain domain : domains) 
        {
            if(domain.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Hilton")) 
            {
                tempList = domains.subList(i, i+2);
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }

        Domain tempDomain;
        tempDomain = tempList.get(1);
        tempList.set(1, tempList.get(0));
        tempList.set(0, tempDomain);

        return domains;
    }

    private List<Domain> sortDomains2(final List<Domain> domains)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < domains.size(); i++) 
        {
            if(domains.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Hilton")) 
            {
                Domain temp = domains.get(i);
                domains.set(i, domains.get(i+1));
                domains.set(i+1, temp);
                i++;
            }
        }

        return domains;
    }

    private class Domain
    {
        private final String name;

        private Domain(final String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        private String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

    private List<Domain> getDomains()
    {
        List<Domain> list = new ArrayList<Domain>();
        list.add(new Domain("Apple"));
        list.add(new Domain("Bing"));
        list.add(new Domain("Google"));
        list.add(new Domain("Hilton"));
        list.add(new Domain("Ink"));
        list.add(new Domain("Facebook"));
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Domains before sorting: [Apple, Bing, Google, Hilton, Ink, Facebook]
Domains after sorting by method1: [Apple, Bing, Google, Ink, Hilton, Facebook]
Domains after sorting by method2: [Apple, Bing, Google, Ink, Hilton, Facebook]
Original list: [Apple, Bing, Google, Hilton, Ink, Facebook]
```

Comment: @raja777m - I've edited my post so that explains in more detail your solution. Added one more extra example.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am underestimating/simplyfing the question but a possible solution:

```
    List<Domain> dmn = new ArrayList<Domain>();
    Iterator<Domain> it = dmn.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Domain dom = it.next();
        if(dom.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Hilton") && it.hasNext()) { // prevents problems if "Hilton" is the last element
        {
            Domain domAfter = it.next();
            System.out.println(domAfter); //do something with the next after Hilton first
            System.out.println(dom);  //do something with Hilton then
        }
        else System.out.println(dom); //else do something with the current element
    }
```

What I am missing from the question is what do you have to do with the elements of the `ArrayList`. This is a not much elegant way you where you don't need to use another list.

Comment: i think it doesn't solve the problem which was:
*Basically i want to change the index of Hilton by 1 value. How can i achieve using list.* It prints it in the order required by the OP but it doesn't return the array in proper order. But maybe it's me who overinterpreted the question ;)

Comment: Hi, please elaborate where I'm doing a mistake.
This is just a temporary workaround though.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What I am missing is what do you mean with _just for one time_. I've understood that you wanted a different ordering just for one iteration but maybe you want the indexes of the two elements (Hilton and the next) switched in a permanent way.

Answer (score 1):

```
int hiltonIndex;
Domain hilton;
for (int i = 0; i < dmn.size(); i++) {
    Domain d = dmn.get(i);
    if(...) {
        hiltonIndex = i; //Save the index of the Hilton Domain
        hilton = d;
    }
    else {
        //I assume you want to do stuff
    }
}
dmn.remove(hiltonIndex);
dmn.add(hilton);
```

Or, basically I just find the index if Hilton, remove it, and then put it back at the end of the list.

If you only want to do this once, then instead of deleting and reentering, simply just do whatever you wanted to do with "Hilton" after the iteration.

Comment: Hi Sherz, i want Ink before Hilton, but the list doesn't end there, so i really can't leave it at the end.
The problem is, i just need to switch the places of those two objects.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
   List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Apple  www.apple.com", "Bing   www.bing.com",
            "Google www.google.com", "Hilton www.hiltonhotels.com ", "Ink    www.ink.com");

    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) { 
        if (list.get(i).contains("Hilton") ) {
           index = i;
           String  s = list.get(i);
           list2.add(list.get(i+1));
        } else {
            list2.add(list.get(i));
        }

    }
    list2.add(index+1, list.get(index));
    for (String st : list2) {
        System.out.println(st + " ");
    }
```

output:

```
Apple  www.apple.com 
Bing   www.bing.com 
Google www.google.com 
Ink    www.ink.com 
Hilton www.hiltonhotels.com
```

**If you do not want to use copy of your list you can do this**

Code:

```
     List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Apple  www.apple.com", "Bing   www.bing.com",
            "Google www.google.com", "Hilton www.hiltonhotels.com ", "Ink    www.ink.com");

    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) {
        if (list.get(i).contains("Hilton") ) {
           index = i;
           String  s = list.get(i);
           System.out.println(list.get(i+1));
        } else {
             System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }

    }
    System.out.println(list.get(index));
```

output:

```
Apple  www.apple.com
Bing   www.bing.com
Google www.google.com
Ink    www.ink.com
Hilton www.hiltonhotels.com
```

Comment: As for your question form the other comment - It works, so it's ok. Yet, the second example doesn't change the order of the list.
This answer has no relation to the solution the OP was suggesting - which was subList() method. There is no explanation - just code.

Comment: subList() return a list